# setting a contextual filter based on a field collection in a view

Tags: views

I'm creating a simple application that is used to create some Contractors and some Projects, 
and what I want to do is displaying on the Contractor's detail page the list of projects the 
contractor has been working on.

I have thus created the simple following data structure :

1. Content type : "Contractors" :

   - Name
   - Address
   - Phone
   - Email
   - Project_list (a view implemented via the "view field" module that should list all the projects for this specific Contractor)
2. Content type : "Projects" : (a project can have several contractors - hence the field collection)

   - Project name
   - Reference
   - Contractors (field collection)
3. Field Collection : "fc_Project_contractors"

   - Contractor (select field that list all the contractors names)
   - Evaluation
   - Comments

My problem : 
For the "Projects" field of the Contractors content type, how should I set up the View Relationship and Contextual filters 
in order to display only the projects of a specific contractor ? 
In the Project content type, if the contractors where selected with a simple taxonomy term or even an Entity reference I'd 
have no problem doing it but with a field collection I tried a lot of settings but without success... either I display all 
of the project or none at all but I cannot display only the relevant ones... I'm stuck with this for quite some time now and
cannot seems to find a solution although I'm pretty sure it's doable..

Any help would be welcome here.. Thanks

Comment: How are you supplying the ID of the contractor? First add your "Contractors" field collection attached to your "Projects" content type as a Relationship to the view. Now you should be able to add the "Contractor" field within your field collection to the Filter Criteria/Contextual Filters with a forced relationship.

Comment: It Works !! Thanks a lot Beebee, now that I've done it I can't see how I missed it..